# How do you override formatting of PDF with Pandoc and an external template

Tags: pandoc

I'm using an external template with Pandoc to customise the title page, headers, footers, etc. when generating PDF's from Markdown.

However, I have not been able to adjust the way quotations look, and neither have I been able to make grid tables draw vertical lines.

If anyone can give an example on this, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For those of us less familiar with pandoc than TeX, can you make clearer what the role of TeX is in this question?  If it is purely a pandoc question then it is off-topic for this site.  I see that you've also put the `latex3` tag on, but I don't see any connection to `latex3` in the question, maybe you could make that clearer as well.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for the friendly suggestion Andrew. Pandoc generates PDF from Markdown via a latex, and you can use a tex [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/mytemplate.tex) for finer control around this generation. I'm trying to modify this template to apply different styling on the document.

Comment: Maybe you could edit that information in to the question to make the connection to TeX clearer.  What would be ideal would be if you could make your question so that someone with no pandoc experience, but expertise in TeX, could potentially answer it.  So if you can isolate the part in the template that deals with the issues you're asking about, that'd be great.  Even if not, at least link to the template in the question and provide a sample document to test with and instructions on how to compile it.